# How to read "Graph Result" in JMeter

Tags: http, jmeter

I am trying to understand the "Graph Result" in JMeter I got when I followed the following scenario:

I am hitting www.google.com with:
No. of users: 10,
Ramp up Period is 5 Seconds,
Loop count is 10

I am finding it difficult to read "Graph Result", I have used another listeners too (View Results in Tree, View Results in Table, Summary Report) which are easy to understand but I would like to learn this too.

Please refer the result Image link:
https://www.cubbyusercontent.com/pli/Image.png/_2855385a0bbb40a0b7cd2d31224b521c

Help appreciated.

Comment: Here's a [good explanation of Graph Results](http://www.coderanch.com/t/561221/Testing/Read-JMeter-graphs-results)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to JMeter Help,

Graph results contains,

> The Graph Results listener generates a simple graph that plots all
> sample times. Along the bottom of the graph, the current sample
> (black), the current average of all samples(blue), the current
> standard deviation (red), and the current throughput rate (green) are
> displayed in milliseconds.
>
> The throughput number represents the actual number of requests/minute
> the server handled. This calculation includes any delays you added to
> your test and JMeter's own internal processing time.

Basically it shows data,average,median,deviation,throughput i.e.system statistics during test in a graphical format.

These values are plotted runtime thus it updates values at bottom at runtime i.e. total no. of samples are no. of samples occurred till that point of time with deviation at that point of time and similarly other counters represent their values.

Due to its runtime behavior, this listener consumes lot of memory and cpu and it is advised that it should not be used while load test (I think you have used it just to know its use and working.)

While running actual load test you can learn/understand these statistics from aggregate report other reports which can be created in non-ui mode also.

I hope this have cleared what graph result shows and how to read it and when to use it.